# Change all associations from gedit to another application

Tags: file-association

I started using Sublime Text 2 a week or so ago and I loved it so much I've spent $60 on it and now want to use it for *everything*.

Gedit currently has ownership of most of the text file associations. I'd essentially like to replace any association to `gedit` with `sublime-text-2`.

Any tips available on bulk association changing? Desktop-neutral methods are preferred.

Comment: Hope my answer (in the last) is the easiest one you can use :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I change file association globally?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/289337/how-can-i-change-file-association-globally)

Comment: @Lucio - Why would you vote to close a question asked a year earlier against a question asked a year later?

Comment: I don't rely on dates to mark a post as duplicated of another one. If one post has no useful content whilst other does, then it should be marked as dupe. If both posts bring useful content over the same issue, then they should be merged. At least that is MHO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set default program?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/90214/how-to-set-default-program)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Running on 13.04+, update the file: /etc/gnome/defaults.list.

```
sudo sed -i 's/gedit.desktop/sublime-text-2.desktop/g' /etc/gnome/defaults.list
```

Credit to [trent](https://askubuntu.com/users/50523/trent) for the update to 13.04+

Pre-13.04:

System wide associations:

```
sudo sed -i 's/gedit.desktop/sublime-text-2.desktop/g' /usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

Just your user's associations:

```
sed -i 's/gedit.desktop/sublime-text-2.desktop/g' ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

Credit to [Oli](https://askubuntu.com/users/449/oli) for the naming convention of the .desktop file before I started using SublimeText2.

Comment: Magic, thanks. I've added what the PPA users (myself included) can use based on your answer.

Comment: Would you mind providing a copy of the .desktop file installed with the PPA version? (For those of use who refuse to install packages from untrusted sources)

Comment: Here is the ppa https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/sublime-text-2/

Comment: Last method works fine also on Ubuntu 14.04
`sudo sed -i 's/gedit.desktop/sublime-text-2.desktop/g' /etc/gnome/defaults.list`

Comment: It should be noted that Sublime Text 3 uses `sublime-text.desktop` which drops the version number instead of incrementing the filename to `sublime-text-3.desktop`

Comment: Use `sudo sed -i 's/gedit.desktop/sublime_text.desktop/g' /etc/gnome/defaults.list` to Sublime Text 3.

Comment: Interesting, in 14.10, I had to change /usr/share/applications/defaults.list (which you indicated was for Pre 13.04 releases).  Since I wanted to use Kate instead of Gedit, I modified your command as follows: sudo sed -i 's|gedit.desktop|kate.desktop|g' /usr/share/applications/defaults.list. (The vertical bars in sed are just a personal preference).

Comment: Answers evolve.  It's whoever makes the decision changing what files are consulted for file association.  At least the needed answer was in there.

Comment: In Ubuntu 20 it's also `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`.

Answer (score 59):

**Update for 16.04 Users:**

Ubuntu tweak has been discontinued. Much of it's functionalities are now being provided by **Unity Tweak Tool** or **Gnome Tweak Tool**. But those still lacks Ubuntu Tweak's *awesome* feature of easy file-type association changing.

To install Ubuntu Tweak on these later version follow the procedure described [on this answer about installing it on 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/819056/61218)

---

There is another way to change the association. It is via using **Ubuntu-tweak**.

1. Install Ubuntu tweak

   - [How do I install Ubuntu-Tweak?](https://askubuntu.com/q/75454/61218)
2. Open it via Dash by typing "Ubuntu tweak"

   [image]
3. After opening it, Click on the **Admin** tab.

   [image]
4. Then click on **File type manager** section

   [image]
5. Then first select the **Text** catagory from the left side bar, and then click on the **Associated Applications** column to sort it by Application name

   [image]
6. After the application is sorted by name, Select the top entry with Gedit, then Press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and click on the last entry with gedit. Then click on the **Edit** button.

   [image]
7. A new window will open where you can see all installed text editor.

   [image]
8. Then select the desired application from list and click close. You can also Click on the **Add** button to add an application which is not installed in pre-defined system folder.

Hope this will help. If you want to reset them, you can click the reset button also.

The good thing in this solution is, you can't accidentally mess up your system .desktop file.

Comment: @dhanvi Just because you answered with another approach doesn't mean you must give a downvote!

Comment: @dhanvi
When we do answer, we typically consider things such as how easy is the solution to follow. I knew several other methods, but it was the easiest. And, setting default was not an option in 12.04 afair. And I have given a way to set several file type simultaneously. FYI, update-alternative is really not an option most of the time.

Comment: maaaan this is best aprroach

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way to do is using the nautilus files not sure if it works for others too

1. select the type of file you want right click and select properties (Alt+Enter is the shortcut)
2. The choose the option open with and then select the one you want as you see here I use atom by default you can also select sublime from the recommended applications [image]

**Command line editor**

you you want to choose the default editor in command line type the following command and then choose the option from there

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

since I use vi I have set it to vim you can choose what ever you want from there also here is the screen shot

[image: screen shot]

If you like this don't forget to vote up this post

Comment: @Oli I think this is the easiest answer hope you agree :)

Comment: easiest solution, in my view (with nautilus, I mean)

Comment: Hope this helped you @mBardos :)

Comment: Your answer is not actually answering the question, since the OP wants a solution that handles multiple file type assignment at once! Please re-read the question

Answer (score -2):

1. Right click on the file
2. Open properties
3. Select the "Open with" tab
4. Choose an application
5. Click on "Set as default"

Screenshot of setting `Sublime Text` as default application:
[image: Set <code>Sublime Text</code> as default application"]

Note: If you right click on a `*.c` file and if you do the above process, then only those files which have the same extension will have the new application as a default one. So similarly you should do the same for all kinds of files. Eg: `*.cpp`, `*.py` etc.

Comment: already mentioned the same in above answer