# How to programmatically edit a file using only terminal?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, editing

I wish to write a shell script whereby I could read the file from command and edit the file without manual intervention (based on searching some text and replacing it with another).

I need not use any text editor for this....simply text-searching (like using grep) and then  replacing it with some other text and saving the changes....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is where `sed` comes in to play. A `sed` command has this format:

```
[pattern1][,pattern2][!] command [args]
```

It uses regexes so it can/will be a bit difficult. Some basic examples taken from the 2nd link below:

```
# substitute (find and replace) "foo" with "bar" on each line
sed 's/foo/bar/' # replaces only 1st instance in a line
sed 's/foo/bar/4' # replaces only 4th instance in a line
sed 's/foo/bar/g' # replaces ALL instances in a line
sed 's/\(.*\)foo\(.*foo\)/\1bar\2/' # replace the next-to-last case
sed 's/\(.*\)foo/\1bar/' # replace only the last case

# substitute "foo" with "bar" ONLY for lines which contain "baz"
sed '/baz/s/foo/bar/g'

# substitute "foo" with "bar" EXCEPT for lines which contain "baz"
sed '/baz/!s/foo/bar/g'

# change "scarlet" or "ruby" or "puce" to "red"
sed 's/scarlet/red/g;s/ruby/red/g;s/puce/red/g' # most seds
gsed 's/scarlet\|ruby\|puce/red/g' # GNU sed only
```

Some references

- [Text Manipulation with sed from linuxjournal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7231)
- [sed one-liners from linuxhowtos](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/sedoneliner.htm)
- [Beginner's guide to sed](http://maketecheasier.com/beginners-guide-to-sed-linux/2012/03/29)

Comment: A seasoned software developer I used to work with used to say: "If you have a problem that you plan to use regular expressions to solve... Well, now you have two problems." ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Very late answer. However, this might help others with a similar problem/question.

I would recommend creating and applying a patch. A nice example can be found
[here](https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/introduction-using-diff-and-patch/).

For example, assuming that a new.txt file contains changes that you want to apply to old.txt. You can execute the commands on a terminal or by creating and executing a patch_file.sh.

Command line: open a terminal and copy and execute the lines below (change the file names as necessary):

```
diff old.txt new.txt > patch.patch # to create the patch
patch old.txt -i patch.patch -o patched_old.text # to apply patch
```

Script: using an .sh file approach. In a terminal (keyboard: ctrl+alt+t: 
`gedit patch_file.sh`

Copy and paste the commands that would go on the terminal, to the .sh file and below the header as shown below (gedit).

```
#!/bin/sh
diff old.txt new.txt > patch.patch # to create the patch
patch old.txt -i patch.patch -o patched_old.text # to apply patch
```

Make the script executable (terminal):

```
chmod +x patch_file.sh
```

Run the script (terminal):

```
./patch_file.sh # may require sudo access depending on the directory affected
```

Comment: +1 patch is always the straight way for medium to heavy or complex modification. I don't know  why some try to do every thing using regex tools .

Comment: +1 so much better than reverse engineering a regex that seems to apply the change you want on the file you test with... but when applied to other instances of that file sometimes has other effects.

Comment: Does a patch make sense if I want to replace all instances of specific text strings, i.e. replace all " " with "_", all "minus" with "-", and all "gb|<string_of_numbers>|ARO:" with "ARO:"? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to edit a file, use a file editor, there are command based file editors that can be used from scripts, like [ex](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html) or [ed](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/doku.php?id=howto%3aedit-ed).

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for sed or awk.  I find sed to be simpler and awk to be more powerful.

Here's an example from [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115113/change-all-associations-from-gedit-to-another-application/115117#115117).

```
sed -i 's/gedit.desktop/yournew.desktop/g' /usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

This means:

- search in file `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`
- Find/grep `gedit.desktop`
- Replace with `yournew.desktop`
- Apply the changes in place `-i`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need to edit, if you're familiar with `vi` then [`ed`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_%28text_editor%29) may be useful.