# Changing default application

Tags: php, default-programs, sublime-text

I have recently installed Sublime text 2 and I must say it's one of the best text editors I've ever used or even seen in use.

So I managed to install everything and added to the unity menu and also change all the entries of gedit.desktop to sublime.desktop and it works just fine for most files, but I realised that some files still open in gedit, for example PHP files.  I checked the default list for PHP, but there isn't anything in there.

How would I set the default for opening PHP files?

---

Also, Sublime doesn't show up in them properties menu where I can usually select the default program.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change all associations from gedit to another application](http://askubuntu.com/questions/115113/change-all-associations-from-gedit-to-another-application)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you didn't install the Sublime package via PPA. You might have downloaded the source.

Here is the steps to install the Sublime package via PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get remove sublime-text*
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

After installing this Right Click on any php file now you will be able to see "Open with Sublime Text 2" or choose "Open with Other Application" and select "Sublime" from the list.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, i think that is the case. Have to questions for you now. First of all how to you find the PPAs? i researched how to install sublime and nothing about it came up. Secondly i have run the first three steps you gave me, when i get to remove it selects packages but doesn't remove them because they're not there, so this means the sublime i installed myself is still on my system, how would i remove that? Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's okay i've sorted that now, i just reverse engineered what i did to install it.

Answer (score 2):

left click on a file go to preferences and change the entry in open With

I hope that helps

Comment: I have tried that but sublime doesn't show up in the list of application. However it does show up when i right click > open with menu. but i can't find it to to set it as default.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to edit file association in this file: `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need to create a *.desktop file for this

Refer to this post: http://theodorbiryukov.blogspot.in/2012/04/ubuntu-sublime-text-2-as-default-text.html