# How do I set Deluge as default Torrent client?

Tags: bittorrent, deluge

I would like to set deluge as primary, but i can't find it in the file system. When i download froma  certain pirating site, it says "choose client to download with" Transmission alaways shows up, but when i try to choose an other application i just can't find deluge in the file system.

Comment: Have you see [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/115113/44179) answer on changing file associations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to install any additional software to change the default program to open a specific archive type. Just open the file manager **Nautilus** and right click the file. Open *Properties* and go to the *Open with* tab. There you choose the default program.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use Ubuntu Tweak. Click on Administration and than on Manage type file. On your left, choose All, find bittorrent file and replace the default program.
(not sure if all the names are correct, because I don't use English language by default)

Comment: I'm a newb :) I'm sorry for wasting your time. I got it thanks!