# how can I change file association globally?

Tags: default-programs, file-association

gedit is set by default to open about any source file. I've gone through the file properties and changed default application to VIM for C and C++ files.

I'd need to do this for any source file I open now, for python files, for text files, for ruby, any, since gedit is set to open all of them.

How can I change this to open with VIM without going the hassle of setting "open with" one by one?

Comment: @DJCrashdummy this is not a duplicate if you take the time to read the discussion in both questions. Besides this being answered correctly by 3+ years already.

Comment: @peper_chico please update the chosen solution accordingly, cause this is misleading

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> **This answer only works in Ubuntu 16.04 or prior**; the comments have a link to a Xenial release of Ubuntu-Tweak. In newer versions of Ubuntu this will not work as Ubuntu-Tweak is no longer supported by the author.
>
> Comments have suggested that *Chris Marx* answer below is the right way, but it does not resolve the answer of administrative management - for example, setting the type for many items.
>
> **Note: Ubuntu 16.04 is still LTS and Ubuntu 14.04 is not EOL**

The EASIEST way for you to do this would be to install the program Ubuntu Tweak.

- [How do I install Ubuntu-Tweak?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak)
- http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/getdeb_apps/xenial/apps/getdeb/ubuntu-tweak

Once you have it downloaded you simply open it up, change to **Admins** tab and then under **System** choose *File Type Manager*. Once in here select the file category *Text* and using shift-click and/or control-click select all of the file types you want, then click **Edit** on the bottom right.

This will allow you to multi-set the mimetype opener for all of the files.

See screen:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZtGN.jpg]

Comment: As I was looking for usability, thanks for this one. Very nice tool.

Comment: is Ubuntu tweak supported for 13.10? I can't install it. http://askubuntu.com/questions/413052/ubuntu-tweak-not-working-is-it-supported-for-13-10 help plz

Comment: @MinaMichael well I use it without problems on 13.10

Comment: @pepper_chico I was having trouble with it; some tabs didn't show anything when I opened them. I uninstalled it and went to the software centre to reinstall it but couldn't find it

Comment: @MinaMichael try synaptic, most of times I prefer it. You may also have to use a PPA, don't recall now if I used one.

Comment: @pepper_chico okay I have synaptic installed but I can't figure out how to use it. help please.

Comment: @MinaMichael for installing just follow the link this answer provides, I have used the PPA installation procedure.

Comment: the download link goes to ubuntu tweak. and by the way "saucy" is not listed! ... I was asking that I can't use Synaptics.

Comment: For those still looking at this answer, you can find new releases and information on the location sites blog. 

For example, for saucy: http://blog.ubuntu-tweak.com/2013/10/13/ubuntu-tweak-0-8-6-released-for-13-10-saucy.html

Comment: Note: Ubuntu tweak isn't supported any more and the link provided does not contain the tool mentioned.

Comment: for anyone looking for this: supported or not there's a xenial package in GetDeb repository: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/getdeb_apps/xenial/apps/getdeb/ubuntu-tweak

Comment: Warning! The current version of Tweaks (at least on Ubuntu 18.04) does not provide this feature.

Comment: @LimpingNinja Have you considered deleting this answer as it is no longer applicable (as consolation - there is badge for such action)

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny I have considered this, but my concern with deleting the answer is that 16.04 is still supported (LTS) and 14.04 is end of support but not yet EOL. Since there is a package for 16.04, I'll add a tag for now - but would like to know if there is a reasonable answer for > 16.04 that covers this actual scenario.

Answer (score 67):

Seems like the answer [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/117709/how-to-change-your-default-applications-on-ubuntu-4-ways/)

is actually the easiest, specifically going to a file's properties, going to the "open with" tab, and then setting as default for that file type. Here's the picture:

[image]

Comment: Again, just as I have commented already in o'rety's answer: "this is not as easy when you want to set multiple file types at once or by mime type" and this question is about this. The chosen answer is still the right one.

Comment: ah my mistake, I was reading that as "setting multiple file's types", not setting multiple default file type associations at once. my mistake-

Comment: This is actually the more natural answer (from the GUI and without manually writing text files or installing 3rd party stuff). It requires a one type at a time setup, though, since Ubuntu does not offer a Open With in a multiple selection -> Properties.

Comment: This option doesn't let me add a third-party app, in my case Adobe Reader.

Comment: @ringø I know I'm 2 years behind, but since I'm still the accepted answer it seems, I need to say that your comment about this being the natural answer doesn't resolve the OP question which specifically asks: "How can I change [all source files] to open with VIM without going the hassle of setting "open with" one by one".

Comment: I followed the instructions and set VLC as the default and now _all_ videos work by opening with it instead.  That option may not be obvious in the process.

Comment: how come this is not the chosen solution?

Answer (score 25):

speaking about how things works globally, for the entire system, the most important thing is

```
/usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

which is the file that holds the associations between a given **mime type** and the application that is supposed to handle that kind of file.

If you don't know the mime type of a file simply use the command

```
mimetype
```

like so

```
mimetype img.jpg 
img.jpg: image/jpeg
```

text files, python scripts, web pages, usually any given file has its own mime type.

Comment: Please update the path(s) in your answer. I'm saying this because I see `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` as a link to `/etc/gnome/defaults.list` in Lubuntu 13.10.

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04 changing `/usr/share/gnome/applications/defaults.list` had no effect for me. Changing `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` as suggested did the trick.

Comment: How do you change the mimetypes of files?

Comment: Make sure to log out for changes to register.

Comment: @becko AFAIK you are unable to change mime type of files, you can change what will open a given mime type.

Comment: @reducingactivity that's quite limiting, though. For example, I need to open plain text files with Text Editor, and Asciidoc (.adoc) files with Atom, but they are recognized as plain text files too, so if I change the default application it'll open them always with Text Editor or always with Atom, which forces me to open them by selecting the proper application every time... it's not strange they're not mapped to a separate mimetype by default, but not having the change to add new mimetypes... meh!

Answer (score 15):

```
touch ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list
```

Add the following lines to ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list

```
[Default Applications]
text/plain=gvim.desktop
```

Now every file on your machine will open with gvim, by default.

Comment: What if I wanted to open console vim in Xterm instead?

Comment: In my current Ubuntu 14 setup this appears to be `mimeapps.list` instead of `defaults.list`.

Comment: @glenatron Ubuntu 15 works with defaults.list

Answer (score 3):

I guess the easiest graphical way would be:

**Files (nautilus)** >> **select a file** >> **right click & Properties**  >> **"Open With" tab** >> **select a program you fancy** >> **"Select as default"**. Done.

This method comes from this post on HowToGeek: http://www.howtogeek.com/117709/how-to-change-your-default-applications-on-ubuntu-4-ways/ where they also talk about how to change default Terminal programs.

Comment: this is not as easy when you want to set multiple file types at once or by mime type

Comment: The OP said explicitly that they are looking for a solution that does *not* involve Open With (see last line of their question).

Comment: This could have been added to the question after my answer had been posted (see the dates).

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Details** from Unity Dash, click on **Default Applications** on the left pane. Change the file associations as per your preference. No additional installation required and you can set all your default applications from one place.

[image]

Comment: This answer does not show a way to handle C++ files, for example.

Comment: Thanks for adding that answer. (Although only for completeness' sake.)

Comment: Think about removing the one in `.local/share/applications/` if you have a strange behavior.