# How to reset default app for filetype?

Tags: 13.10, gedit, default-programs, ubuntu-tweak

How can I set a filetype to always open with a specific application?

In `.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` there was this line `-
application/x-extension-jap=gedit.desktop;jalbum.desktop;`

It always opens with `gedit`, and `jalbum` does not appear in the *Open with* list.

Since `jalbum` should be (and always used to be) the default application, I changed it to
`application/x-extension-jap=jalbum.desktop;gedit.desktop;`

But that doesn't seem to change anything.

In answers to similar questions "Ubuntu Tweak" has been suggested as a way to manage this problem, but that option seems to have disappeared from current versions of "Tweak".

I tried fixing this using the Nautilus *Properties* display, but `jalbum` doesn't show up there as an alternative application.

Is there some other way to fix this?

---

**Update**

@JohnnyD
It seems that the edit that I described actually worked, but needed a restart to take effect.

But the second app listed in `mimeapps.list` (gedit) is now not available in "Open with", and if I choose it from "Other applications", then jalbum disappears again!

It also seems that when I originally searched for "Ubuntu Tweak" in the Software Centre I found "Unity Tweak" which appears to be a different animal, so my earlier comments about "Ubuntu Tweak" really applied to "Unity Tweak" instead.

So the immediate problem was resolved, but -
with regard to your suggested solutions, I couldn't see any way in "Open with" to insert an app manually that doesn't already appear in the list.

And I couldn't see in "Unity tweak Tool" a way to register a filetype that isn't already in the "File Type" list.

Comment: Or this question [how can I change file association globally?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/289337/how-can-i-change-file-association-globally)

Answer (score 0):

right click on a file you wish to open navigate to `properties` at the bottom then navigate to `open with` there you can see the default app for given format and you can change or replace it with desired one, if it's not listed search for it manually of course, for example `/usr/bin/` appname.

Also you can install Ubuntu-tweak:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

run it when it's opened navigate to admins/file type manager and find and choose format for changing.