# How to change default program for files ending in one extension

Tags: file-format

In Ubuntu 18.** how do I set a default program only for files with one specific file extension? For example if I use the graphical interface and use "Set as default" for a .txt file it also changes the default setting for files with many other extensions. I don't want this. How can I change the default program only for files with a specific extension?

Comment: This may be related to a bug in the current version of nautilus. See @kakunka's answer (with comment) here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/90214/how-do-i-set-the-default-program

Answer (score 2):

This answer is adapted from [Ondra Žižka](https://askubuntu.com/users/41425/ondra-%c5%bdi%c5%beka)'s answer here: [How do I set the default program?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90214/how-do-i-set-the-default-program). Please upvote there as well if this helps you.

To change the default program for files with a specific file type, a mime type needs to be created for each file extension. This is because Ubuntu tracks this indirectly:

- file extension -> MIME types
- MIME type -> application(s) to open
- Applications -> list of compatible MIME types

For Ubuntu (18.x), the following applies:

#### file extension -> MIME types

This is determined from files in `/usr/share/mime/packages/`.
  E.g.:

```
cat << EOF | sudo tee /usr/share/mime/packages/staruml.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
  <mime-type type="application/staruml-project">
    <comment>StarUML project</comment>
    <glob pattern="*.MDJ"/>
    <glob pattern="*.mdj"/>
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>
EOF
```

Other xml files are generated from these and placed in `/usr/share/mime/`. Sometimes these files may be found online, especially for open source software packaged for Ubuntu. For example, the mime files for [KiCad](https://www.kicad-pcb.org/) can be found in the KiCad source code repository: https://gitlab.com/kicad/code/kicad/-/tree/master/resources/linux/mime

#### MIME type -> application(s) to open

This is driven by `~/.config/mimeapps.list` or possibly `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`. This should override `/usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list`. For example:

```
echo 'application/staruml=staruml.desktop' | tee -a ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

Or, to change for all users:

```
echo 'application/staruml=staruml.desktop' | sudo tee -a /usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

#### Applications -> list of compatible MIME types

This is driven by the `.desktop` files in `/usr/share/applications/`. That file can contain a `MimeType=` entry with semicolon-separated list of MIME types. For instance, the EOG app has `MimeType=image/bmp;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/jpg;...`.

```
cat << EOF | sudo tee /usr/share/applications/staruml.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=StarUML
Comment=StarUML
GenericName=StarUML
Exec=/sw/prog/StarUML/StarUML-3.1.0-x86_64.AppImage %U
Icon=/sw/prog/StarUML/staruml.png
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
Categories=Development;Programming;Modeling;UML
MimeType=application/staruml-project;
EOF
```

---

This makes it a full circle. The changes take effect after running

```
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

and, for icons,

```
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/gnome -f
```

Or, you may need to logout/login.

Then, mimetypes for a given file extension can be checked using `mimetype`:

```
$ mimetype .mdj
.mdj:  application/staruml-project
```

References:

- [How do I set the default program?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90214/how-do-i-set-the-default-program)
- https://coderwall.com/p/qjda2q/create-new-mime-type-and-assign-an-icon-to-it-in-ubuntu
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingMimeTypes
- [How to assign (set) a MIME type to a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/586476/how-to-assign-set-a-mime-type-to-a-file)

Credit: [Ondra Žižka](https://askubuntu.com/users/41425/ondra-%c5%bdi%c5%beka) (Adapted)