# How to programatically get program associated with a given file extension?

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, settings, default, file-format

How can I without any manual GUI use check what will open file with a specific file extension - for example `.rb`?

Not a duplicate of [how can I change file association globally?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289337/how-can-i-change-file-association-globally) as mine is about programmatically reading, not changing in any way, including manual through GUI (though https://askubuntu.com/a/289339/349903 hints that parsing some set of config files may give an answer)

To avoid XY problem: I have system installation script, that works fine except that Okular ends associated with `.rb`, `.py`, `.txt` and other text files, instead of text editor. I want to rerun installation script and log what is now opening specific file extensions after every step. I hope that will allow me to debug what is going wrong.

Comment: The problem is that file associations are based on mimetype, not file extension. If you know the mimetype(s) in question then you may be able to use `xdg-mime ` to query the default association ex. `xdg-mime query default text/plain`

Comment: `touch test.rb` + `mimetype test.rb` gives me `test.rb: application/x-ruby` what allows me to run `xdg-mime query default application/x-ruby` Are you interested in making an answer?

Comment: As much as it's great that you're checking other sites for your answer, you don't have to defend your question as "not duplicate" against questions on other sites.  There isn't really such a thing as a duplicate question across sites, only questions that are duplicate on the same site (real duplicate), or off-topic questions more appropriate to another site (which will be transferred by a mod).  I only mention this because the defence is actually distracting to the question, which is assumed to be on Ubuntu anyway.

Comment: @tu-ReinstateMonica-dorduh I removed pointless part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To sum up the comments above the answer to this problem is a two step process:

First determine the MIME type of the file:

```
MIMETYPE=$(xdg-mime query filetype "<your-file-here>")
```

Then get the default application associated with this type:

```
xdg-mime query default "$MIMETYPE"
```

So the mime type could be **text/x-python** for example and the application would be **gedit.desktop** on my system.

You can also make this a one liner:

```
xdg-mime query default "$(xdg-mime query filetype '<your-file-here>')"
```