# double-click does not open the default program

Tags: nautilus, latex

I installed Ubuntu 12.04, with `texlive-full` and `texworks`. When I double-click a `.tex` file in Nautilus, it pops up a

```
Do you want to run "xxxxxxxx.tex", or display it contents?

"xxxxxxxx.tex" is an executable text file.

Run in Terminal     Display       Cancel        Run
```

If I choose `Display`, it opens `texworks`. How can I make it open without seeing the above conversation window?

By the way, is `.tex` file indeed an executable file?

---

ADDED
Just for the case, my `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` file looks like the following:

```
[Default Applications]
text/html=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/http=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/about=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/unknown=google-chrome.desktop
text/x-tex=texworks.desktop
x-scheme-handler/mailto=google-chrome.desktop

[Added Associations]
text/x-tex=texworks.desktop;
text/x-bibtex=jabref.desktop;gedit.desktop;
```

I observe texworks are both up and down. Should I remove one?

---

ADDED

This does not happen with all .tex files. In fact, I am currently using Ubuntu 12.04 under Virtual Box with Windows 7 host. I have my Dropbox account synced with the Windows 7 host, and I access files in Dropbox in Ubuntu through Virtual Box's shared folder functionality. (I didn't install Dropbox client in Ubuntu.)

Files in Dropbox are owned by `root` with group `vboxsf`. My personal account is in the group `vboxsf`.

It seems that I have to uncheck the option for "executable", but I have all my .tex files in the Dropbox shared folder. Would there be any workaround?

Comment: I don't think so, I have an entry in both spots.  Just to clarify, this is happening with *all* .tex files? What program are you creating them in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uncheck execute permission from .tex file properties, mentioned conversation window won't come again.

You can also change this behaviour globally by opening nautilus (file manager) and go to menu **EDIT > PREFERENCES > BEHAVIOUR** and under "Executable Text Files" check option "view executable text files when they are opened".

Comment: I added more details regarding the issue with Dropbox and Virtual Box

Comment: I have edited my answer according to details you've added.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the `.tex` file, and choose **properties**.  In the dialog box that opens go to the **Open With** tab and select `texworks` as the **Default Application**.

No `.tex` is not an executable file, its a type of text file.

[How to set default program?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90214/how-to-set-default-program)  Has some more methods, such as Ubuntu Tweak.

**EDIT:**

Any text file can be considered executable if executable permissions are set.  Try removing execute permissions in *properties*.

This would fix one file although if all your .tex  files are doing this then they are being created with the wrong permissions for some reason.

Comment: texworks is already the default application. I will try Ubuntu Tweak. .... texworks is also the default application seen in Ubuntu Tweak.

Answer (score 0):

I found this workaround:

HowTo Remove Executable Flag from Files in Virtual Box Shared Folder on Linux Guest

http://polach.cc/howto-remove-executable-flag-from-files-in-virtual-box-shared-folder-on-linux-guest

However, Umair's answer worked enough for me.