# Nautilus doesn't open .tex files on left-click (12.04)

Tags: nautilus, latex

When I left-click a file with .tex extension from nautilus, it is not opened. No matter if I choose gedit or texmaker as default programs in "Properties". Right-clicking, then choosing app works, though. Left-clicking files with other extensions also works fine. Why is that and how can I change it?

Comment: this file should have `execute` bit. Is it placed on `NTFS` partition?

Comment: It is on the main partition (ext4) in my personal folder. Owner has read/write/execute rights.

Comment: Clicking the same file from the **dash** works fine. It is then opened with the default app I have entered in the nautilus properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found an answer in this thread:

**[double-click does not open the default program](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150160/double-click-does-not-open-the-default-program)**

(I should have mentioned that in fact I meant double-click, not left-click. I forgot that double-click is default in Nautilus and I just changed it to left-click in my properties. Anyway, problem occured in any case.)

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, it does. Accepted.