# Xubuntu/precise: default programs chaos

Tags: xfce, default-programs

I'm using xubuntu "precise".

I have set up my preferred applications (Settings/Preferred-Applications or `$ exo-preferred-applications`):

- web browser: chromium
- mail reader: thunderbird
- file manager: thunar
- terminal emulator: xfce4-terminal

However, some programs have their own ideas:

- clicking the terminal icon in the xfce panel opens xfce4-terminal but Thunar's "open terminal here" opens NextStep terminal.
- clicking a link in thunderbird or the terminal opens it in chromium, clicking a link in a PDF in evince fails with "Failed to execute child process "/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome" (No such file or directory)". Clicking a link in OpenOffice opens firefox whereas alpine prefers to open links in epiphany.
- "Open containing folder" in evince fails with "Failed to execute default file manager - Failed to execute child process "/usr/bin/Thunar" (Permission denied)." (Doubly odd as said application exists and runs fine on the command line.) Other programs prefer to launch nautilus instead.

What settings to I have to set so that every application that needs a browser/terminal/file manager uses the correct one? Getting evince to open hyperlinks correctly and Thunar my xfce terminal are my priorities, everything else would be nice.

Answer (score -1):

You may have to change "desktop specific" applications (e.g. Nautilus to Gnome, Dolphin to KDE, ...) via the desktop specific control applications.

So for Gnome use `gnome-control-center` and for KDE `systemsettings` and set the default applications.

Comment: Ok, after setting chromium as default in gnome-control-center, ckicling a link in evince fails with `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser-sandbox: error while loading shared libraries: libpthread.so.0: failed to map segment from shared object: Permission denied`. Chromium is installed and works fine.

Comment: There is some bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apparmor/+bug/964510

Comment: Another note on gnome-control-center: for some reason, when an XFCE session is running, most options in the center don't appear for me. I had to log out and in again with a "GNOME session" to get the settings button to appear in the control center.
There doesn't seem to be an option to set the default _terminal_ there though?

Comment: Does this work: http://askubuntu.com/questions/90214/how-to-set-default-program?rq=1