# I can't associate .torrent with Transmisson

Tags: transmission

I’m terrible with computers and I recently updated my Ubuntu. I don’t know what to and I can't torrent because it asks me what to open with and I can't find transmission to open torrents with. Please help.

It asks me what to open them with and before the update, it used Transmission as my default and I can't figure out to set it back as my default. I've tried finding multiple times and I can't and I don’t know what to do.

Comment: possible duplicated http://askubuntu.com/q/90214/169736

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/q/366280/349837). Maybe the easiest way is to `apt purge transmission` and then `install`. Also, you can [associate Torrent's manget links to transmission-gtk.desktop](https://askubuntu.com/a/1023143/349837)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why that is happening but you might
want to open up synaptic Package manager and just
reinstall Transmission and transmission-common.
That should fix it fast