# URL protocol handlers in basic Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: gnome, dconf, url

There was a way to register URL protocol handlers with Gconf, which is now obsolete and there seems to be no way to do the same with DConf (or Gsettings, its recommended wrapper).

How do one properly register an URL protocol handlers since DConf?

Additionally, something looks strange to me (as I don't understand it), on my Ubuntu 12.04

The protocol `apt://` should be handled by the `apturl` command. It is so with my Opera browser, but only because I added this specific association using the browser's configuration facility. Otherwise, in the rest of the environment:

- Running `xdg-open apt://foo.bar` opens `elinks` (my `www-browser` alternative).
- Running `gnome-open apt://foo.bar` opens the Software Center.
- Opening `gconf-editor`, I see a key `/desktop/gnome/url-handlers/apt` whose value is `apturl "%s"` and it's enabled. This configuration seems to be ignored, which is reasonably expected, as GConf is considered obsolete.
- Opening `dconf-editor`, I can't see anything related to URL handlers or protocols in `/desktop/gnome`

It looks a bit messy to my eyes (just teasing with this wording, nothing bad)

What's underneath?

Side note: I'm looking for something which preferably works even when the full desktop environment is not loaded, like when running an i3wm session with only `gsettings-daemon` (and other stuff unrelated to this case) loaded.

### Update

Another way to “register” a protocol handler is with `*.desktop` files and their MIME-Type; e.g. `MimeType=application/<the-protocol>;`.

I found a `/usr/share/applications/ubuntu-software-center.desktop` with this content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Ubuntu Software Center
GenericName=Software Center
Comment=Lets you choose from thousands of applications available for Ubuntu
Exec=/usr/bin/software-center %u
Icon=softwarecenter
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=PackageManager;GTK;System;Settings;
MimeType=application/x-deb;application/x-debian-package;x-scheme-handler/apt;
StartupNotify=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=software-center
Keywords=Sources;PPA;Install;Uninstall;Remove;Purchase;Catalogue;Store;
```

This one explains why `gnome-open apt://foo.bar` opens the Software Center instead of `apturl`.

So I installed this `apturl.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/usr/bin/apturl %u
Name=APT‑URL
Comment=APT‑URL handler
Icon=
Categories=Application;Network;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/apt;
```

After `update-desktop-database` and even after rebooting, both `xdg-open` and `gnome-open` still do the same and ignore this user desktop file, which as usual with user desktop‑files, should override the one in `/usr/share/applications/`.

Maybe there is something special with desktop files specifying `x-scheme-handler` MIME type and they are not handled the usual way.

The desktop‑file way does not answer the question.

Comment: This may help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/100736

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Open `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` and add a line like:

```
x-scheme-handler/apt=apturl.desktop
```

Comment: Ya, I could figure it for HTTP, MAILTO and some others.

Comment: There is no such folder. I did a search from root, and didn't find it.

Comment: @VlasBashynskyi, the location of `mimeapps.list` may vary. I would suggest to run a search for the file name.

Answer (score 20):

### [`xdg-mime`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/xdg-mime.1.html)

Maybe more elegant (in this example I use *"apt"*, change it for any other scheme):

1. Check registered MIME-types in `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`.
2. Add the `apt.desktop` file ([here some examples](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/apa.html)) to `~/.local/share/applications/` (user-wide) or `/usr/share/applications/` (system-wide).
3. Build cache database of MIME types handled by desktop files (may need `sudo`):
   [`update-desktop-database`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/update-desktop-database.1.html)
4. Register a protocol with

   ```sh
   xdg-mime default apt.desktop x-scheme-handler/apt
   ```

This will append the new MIME Type for the scheme to either `~/.config/mimeapps.list` or `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`. You can register the new mime-type for all users on the system `sudo xdg-mime install --mode system <xml file>`.

Test with [`xdg-open "apt://foo.bar"`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open).

See also [Adding a MIME Type](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingMimeTypes).

Answer (score 1):

When launching href links that look like:

```
zoommtg://zoom.us/join?action=join&confno=000000
```

This is what worked for me with zoom

```
echo "x-scheme-handler/zoommtg=Zoom.desktop" >> ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

Comment: Thanks for finally making your first post after more than 7 years of being a member here.  Please take the [tour].  It is good to post resolving answers, but it is always more valuable to the asker and thousands of future researchers if you can support your answer with legitimate external documentation or a break down of how/why your solution works.  If you can improve your answer, please [edit] your answer at any time, as many times as needed (there is no limit).