# How do I associate a file type with an appimage?

Tags: .desktop, default-programs, krita, appimage

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I've downloaded the latest krita appimage
(http://files.kde.org/krita/3/linux/krita-3.0-x86_64.appimage)

I want to be able to open Krita files (with the extension ".kra", mime-type "application/x-krita") with this appimage, by double-clicking the file icon.

How do I do this?

I have tried moving the appimage to /usr/share/applications, I've tried adding a desktop file /usr/share/applications/krita.desktop with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Krita
Exec=/usr/share/applications/krita-3.0-x86_64.appimage %F
Type=Application
MimeType=application/x-krita
```

I've made sure both files have the same permissions as other files in the same directory.

Krita does not appear under "Open With Other Application…"

Comment: 3.0.1 doesn't =( would like to get this working too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Got this working on Mint 18.1 Cinnamon.

The .appimage of Krita 3.1.2 didn't add any file associations, so I created a file named krita.desktop, and put the following inside:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Krita
Comment=Krita, An open source painting and drawing application.
Exec=[path to .appimage] %F
Type=Application
Icon=[path to icon]
Categories=Graphics; 
MimeType=image/krita;
```

I made that file executable, then copied it to `/usr/share/applications`.

Next I opened `~/.config/mimeapps.list`, and appended:

```
image/krita=krita.desktop;
```

under the section [Added Associations]

Finally, I right-clicked a `.kra` file and chose Krita as the default app under Open With.

Hope that helps someone out.

Comment: I played around with this a little, and ended up with both mime-types ("image/krita" and "application/x-krita") in both files (separate by the ; in krita.desktop, on separate lines in mimeapps.list), but it's working for me now, thanks.

Comment: System-wide: `.desktop` on `/usr/share/applications/` ← `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`. User-wide: `~/.local/share/applications/` ← `~/.config/mimeapps.list`. Also, could [register with `xdg-mime`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1023143/349837)

Answer (score 3):

The next version of the Krita AppImage will come with desktop integration which should do this for you automatically.

You can try an alpha build:
https://krita.org/en/item/krita-3-0-1-alpha-builds/