# How to make a .appimage file a default program

Tags: appimage

So I have a .AppImage file:
[AppImage files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34Y31.png)

Now I *can* right-click and run the AppImage as a program:
[Run as program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cj5mf.png)

Then I have an obscure file ending:
[Weird File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nes93.png)

And I want to make the default program for opening this weird file be my .AppImage, but when I look at the default programs, I can't find it:
[Default open with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bf7Y0.png)

I've tried chmod with the terminal:
[chmod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD2Vl.png)

Nothing seems to work! Please help!

Comment: Questions should be able to answer without the NEED for images. Although images are helpful, they should not be required to understand your problem.

Comment: @karel Thanks so much for the link! I think it will work!

Comment: @AlexFullinator What did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to regsiter the .appimage with  Ubuntu. Take a look on this [Similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819782/how-do-i-associate-a-file-type-with-an-appimage) that gave example how to register the .appimage and then use it as default to other files.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! I believe that the link you gave me has what I need!