# Is there soemthing like iOS's universal links for ubuntu

Tags: application-development, desktop-environments, .desktop, development

I am currently developing an application that supports universal links on iOS / MacOS, app links on android and apps for websites on windows. Therefore when a user clicks on a link for my app, for example https://my.cool.app/app/ , it opens my app.
Is this also possible on Ubuntu or are only custom schemes available on Ubuntu like: mycoolapp://app/ ?

Comment: Please explain more about what you mean by universal links. People who don't develop on iOS may not be familiar with this concept

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL protocol handlers in basic Ubuntu Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/514125/url-protocol-handlers-in-basic-ubuntu-desktop)

Comment: Linux has been capable of doing this since a long while before "universal links" came out (couple of decades, now, I think). You just create a scheme handler for whatever protocol you want.