# How do I change which application opens xml documents by default?

Tags: default-programs

I am on 14.04 and want to set a custom application (subtitleeditor) to open xml files. This question does not apply to me: [How to set default program?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90214/how-to-set-default-program) because not matter what I do, the default program to open xml files stays the default browser set by System setings>Details>Default applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you click a link in a browser, it is the browser which decides what program to use. In Firefox, thatcan be changed on the "applications" tab in the Preferences.

Clicking a .xml file name in the Files manager or on the desktop should launch the default program. To change that, right-click on a .xml file, choose Properties, and click the "Open with" tab.

Comment: My case is your second paragraph. And does this work for you with -xml files? Because it does not for me. Ok, I tried with guest user and it works even for .xml files. So there is something wrong with my profile. Any ideas which files might need resetting to default values to fix this? "Bisecting" .home is a bit tiresome.

Comment: Edit `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`. Delete the line that contains `application/xml`. Then proceed as above.

Comment: @Jos in my case, my mimeapps.list is empty.