# does anyone know how to install exagear desktop on chromebook with xfce ubuntu?

Tags: dpkg, deb, chromebook

I'm having problems with Exagear can someone help me? I use the terminal and every thing nothing works. I use this command and I keep getting this error:

```
sudo dpkg -i exagear-guest-ubuntu-1204lts_9_all.deb
dpkg: error processing exagear-guest-ubuntu-1204lts_9_all.deb (--install):
cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
exagear-guest-ubuntu-1204lts_9_all.deb
```

Comment: where did you download it to?

Comment: downloads folder

Comment: and what if you run: `sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/exagear-guest-ubuntu-1204lts_9_all.deb` does it do anything?

Comment: @JoKeR you might wanna post it as an answer. I think that's what OP really needed, since his `$(pwd)`  was `/home/username` if you get what i mean

Comment: yes @Serg I understand I'll post it, just wanted to be sure what's going on exactly ;)

Answer (score 1):

When you download a `.deb` package and want to run it with `dpkg` installer like:

```
sudo dpkg -i exagear-guest-ubuntu-1204lts_9_all.deb
```

You have to show it the correct way where is it? For example in Dowloads folder, then:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/exagear-guest-ubuntu-1204lts_9_all.deb
```

or complete path will look like:

```
sudo dpkg -i /home/username/Downloads/exagear-guest-ubuntu-1204lts_9_all.deb
```

Also you can `cd` to the folder where you downloaded `.deb` package e.g.:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

Then you can simply run:

```
sudo dpkg -i exagear-guest-ubuntu-1204lts_9_all.deb
```

Alternatives.

Just type:

```
sudo dpkg -i
```

And you can just drag & drop `.deb` package into a terminal and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Other way `gdebi` installer:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Just right click on a file and choose `install with gdebi` or [make it default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606858/how-to-set-default-program-to-open-specific-file-type/606871#606871) for `.deb` packages and just double click on a file. Gdebi will automatically check for the dependencies and install the package.