# VLC not showing up in Nautilus or default apps

Tags: nautilus, vlc

I've installed VLC, and want to make it default. However, VLC isn't there,  in the Open with... context menu in Nautilus OR the Default Apps section in System Settings.

Here is a screenshot to show what I'm talking about:

[image]

As you can see, the only thing available is Totem, the default app. (and yes, I did click on 'Show All Programs' before, it's not there either)

I've purged and reinstalled VLC a number of times, and even purged and reinstalled Nautilus.

**How can I add VLC to the available video apps?**

[Default Program Selection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636527/default-program-selection) -- I've already tried the solutions listed here. VLC does not appear.

Comment: I am having the same problem and hope somebody finds a solution