# Atom editor not showing up in 'Other Applications' list in Nautilus Open With

Tags: nautilus, atom

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm trying to set Atom as my default text editor to open files as well not just through shell. However, it won't even appear in my other applications list.

[atom not present in applications list picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbCF0.png)

Then, I tried using instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636527/default-program-selection) but there's nothing in my mimeapps.list file even related to text except the text/html first line.

```
[Default Applications]
text/html=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/http=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/about=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/unknown=google-chrome.desktop
```

Sorry if this has been answered elsewhere but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I moved my `/usr/share/applications/atom.desktop`  to `~/.local/share/applications/` and that solved my problem.

Comment: based on this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/732464/sublime-text-not-showing-in-nautilus-open-with-menu