# How can I change the default application for hyperlinks?

Tags: default, default-programs

When I follow hyperlinks on Ubuntu 19.04, I am directed to the GUI of R. How can I change this so the hyperlink is directed to firefox?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/79306/925971

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/files-open.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set default program to open specific file type](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606858/how-to-set-default-program-to-open-specific-file-type)

Comment: Also, the only detailed support we can offer you per http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic , since your 19.04 version has reached End of Life, is how to upgrade to a supported version. Those are 19.10, 18.04LTS and 16.04LTS.

Comment: @Gryu I did this but I still have the same problem

Comment: @K7AAY when I right click on the links, the only two options I'm given are "Follow this link" and "Copy Link address." PS I'm using Okular and I'm starting to suspect that I should change something with the settings of Okular, so I'll dig into that to see if that helps