# Add Google Chrome to Default Applications

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

I am a new Ubuntu user. After initial install of my OS one of the first things I did was install Google Chrome (google-chrome-stable) from the Google website. Everything was good, it showed as an option in System->Details->Default Applications menu and I set it as default browser. A few days later, here I am looking at my Default Applications menu and Google Chrome is nowhere to be found. My default has reverted to Firefox. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the google-chrome-stable package but to no avail. How can I get Google Chrome to reappear as an option in Default Applications list?

Comment: I should note I am using Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Have you tried : Uninstalling firefox than installing chrome and setting it as default later if you want install firefox again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set default program?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/90214/how-to-set-default-program)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it! Somehow I had a corrupt google-chrome.desktop in my ~/.local/share/applications/ folder. I found the file in /usr/share/applications/ was valid. After deleting the bad one in my ~/.local/share/applications/ folder, logging out and back in, everything is back to normal. I can select Google Chrome from Default Applications and everything is golden.

Comment: This was exactly what fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set Chrome as default browser directly from Chrome settings. Have a look at the icon on top right of any Chrome tab (the three lines) and then Settings --> Default browser.

Comment: Chrome says it is currently the default browser. However, the Default Applications menu in Ubuntu shows Firefox as the default, and doesn't list Google Chrome.

Comment: When I click on a URL, FIrefox launches, so Google Chrome may think it is the default, but it isn't actually working.

Comment: And if you open a link on a .pdf or from any other application, it opens in Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: If you check on Firefox settings, it thinks to be the default browser as well?

Comment: Yes, both browsers list themselves as the default. Actual behavior indicates Firefox is the default.

Comment: And I know, it does not really solve the problem, but do you need them both? Why don't you uninstall Firefox?

Comment: Unfortunately, I need Firefox for a few websites where Java in Chrome isn't working.

Comment: So I cannot help you, I have Ubuntu 15.10 too, but I have in my list of default apps both Firefox and Chrome (I'm talking, of course, about System settings --> Details --> Default Apps)  :( Sorry!