# Setting sublime text as default for all Java files

Tags: java, default, default-programs, sublime-text

Incidentally, I have RStudio & R installed on my laptop. So I don't know why but when I double-click on `.java` files, they open by default in RStudio.

Every time I have to right-click and choose Sublime/Gedit as preferred choice to open these files in a proper text-editor. Can someone guide me on how to set Sublime as default for `.java` files(so that I can open them in Sublime with a simple double-click)?

**UPDATED REQUEST:** It would be much helpful if a way of doing this using terminal (or a way without using the Unity interface).

My question is partially different from [How to set default program?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90214/how-to-set-default-program) in that I preferably need a terminal-using way.

Comment: Please see my edited answer for the terminal way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## GUI Way:

1. Right-click the file.
2. Go to Properties
3. Go to the "open with" tab.
4. Select the program you want, and click <kbd>Set as Default</kbd>. (I don't have Sublime, so it's not in the list)

[image]

---

## Terminal way:

`cd` into the directory containing your file and do:

```
mimeopen -d your-source-code.java
```

Sample output:

```
Please choose a default application for files of type text/x-java

    1) notepad  (wine-extension-txt)
    2) LibreOffice Writer  (libreoffice-writer)
    3) gedit  (gedit)
    4) Other...

use application #
```

---

<sup>Note: credit for the terminal way goes to [Ugo Hed's](https://askubuntu.com/users/519534/ugo-hed) answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/755168/518562).</sup>