# Change Default Applications from Script

Tags: command-line, scripts, 18.04, default-programs

**How can I change the default applications from the command line (specifically from a script)?**

The link below describes setting the default applications from the GUI, and also by editing `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`. However, it appears `mimeapps.list` has been moved or is no longer present.

See, e.g.,
[How do I set the default program?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90214/how-do-i-set-the-default-program)

Comment: Have you tried to create the file in question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After using my system for some time, it appears one of my programs caused the file to be created at ~/.config/mimeapps.list

```
sudo find / -name "mimeapps.list"

cat ~/.config/mimeapps.list

[Added Associations]
image/jpeg=gimp.desktop;
text/x-java=eclipse_eclipse.desktop;
application/json=sublime_text.desktop;
application/rdf+xml=sublime_text.desktop;
text/x-python=sublime_text.desktop;
video/mp4=vlc.desktop;
application/octet-stream=org.gnome.Software.desktop;
application/pdf=evince.desktop;
text/html=org.gnome.gedit.desktop;
text/plain=firefox.desktop;

[Default Applications]
application/ppdf=FoxitReader.desktop
application/octet-stream=FoxitReader.desktop
application/pdf=FoxitReader.desktop
```