# How to make a terminal command a default "open with" option

Tags: wine, 20.04

So I installed wine and I want to make wine the default program for .exe files but I don't have it in the "open with" tab. I know this was possible in Linux Mint, but I have no idea how to do it here in Ubuntu 20.04 in the default desktop.

Comment: here?  What OS/release are you using?  Currently we don't know (including what desktop you are using if not the default)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the default program?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90214/how-do-i-set-the-default-program)

Comment: well yes but actually no becouse i need to do the same thing but not with a program but a terminal command