# How to open .webm video files in vlc(or any other media player) by default in 16.04?

Tags: vlc, webm

I downloaded a bunch of lectures using youtube-dl. But all of those videos have .webm extension. Everytime I need to open the videos by right clicking>>Open with>>VLC.

How do I make it open by default in VLC?

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. Right click on the .webm file.
2. Goto properties.
3. Select `Open With` tab and choose `vlc`.
4. Click set as default.

Comment: There is no "set as default" option. And to my knowledge, one can't set a default application directly in 16.04. You need to go to Settings>>Details>>Default Applications

Comment: You might find your answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90214/how-do-i-set-the-default-program)

Comment: Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/755168/1053060)