# xdg-open preferes opening pdf files with libreoffice rather than Document viewer since I removed Adobe?

Tags: pdf, xdg-open

I removed Adobe from my Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and, since then, `xdg-open file.pdf` opens the file with `libreoffice` rather than Document viewer. Purging `libreoffice` completely solves the problem, however it persists if I re-install it. I could live like this, where I remove and re-install libreoffice, since I don't use it much in the first place, however I believe that there should be a fix for this. Is there a way to tell `xdg-open` *Please, open pdfs with this other app*? I did do some googling but I couldn't find anything clear-cut that I could understand.

Edit: there's not tick to do when opening a pdf file, so I have no way to chose a default app from there

[image: no tick]

Thank you very much

Edit2: the suggested similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90214/how-do-i-set-the-default-program) is somehow not applicable for me, I see none of the options listed for the GUI solution in my system and I don't fully understand the non-GUI solution. On the other hand, the suggested (comments) `xdg-mime default org.gnome.Evince.desktop application/pdf` command works wonderfully!

Comment: Right click in files > Open with, then select document viewer while checking "Always use for this file type"?

Comment: Hello, there's nothing to tick, I will show you in the edit of the question

Comment: How about setting it in terminal with `xdg-mime default org.gnome.Evince.desktop application/pdf`?

Comment: Amazing! That did do the trick! Feel free to put it down as an answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the default program?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90214/how-do-i-set-the-default-program)

Comment: Both of those answers I knew I saw around here, but I didn't remember exactly where, until I found them in that linked question. I would much rather give credit by flagging than taking credit by posting an answer

Comment: In my linked question, you need to scroll down to the answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/1112097/1004020 , but if you learned about desktop file names from me, then sure, I can post an answer

Comment: I see, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes the file association GUI may be confusing, unreliable, and different across Ubuntu releases, so the command line is a reliable way of [setting it](https://askubuntu.com/a/1112097/1004020):

```bash
xdg-mime default org.gnome.Evince.desktop application/pdf
```

I looked in `/usr/share/applications` for the right `*.desktop` file name. In this case, you specifically want the *Document Viewer* app and it is internally named *`org.gnome.Evince.desktop`*. `xdg-mime default` is just the command to change file associations. `application/pdf` is the MIME type for PDF files.